# Google apps - Naked alias redir

Tags: google-apps

I've www.somedomain.com.uy and somedomain.com.uy. Because i use google apps for this domain on my google app panel, i've setup a naked redir from somedomain.com.uy to www.

So, what i currently have is on Domains tabs are:

> somedomain.com.uy (primary domain). With the naked redirect set to www.somedomain.com.uy
>   somdomain.uy. (alias domain)

On my google app panel, i went to Add domain, and added www.somedomain.uy to my app.

As i result of all this, i can access this application from:

> somedomain.com.uy
>   www.somedomain.com.uy
>   www.somedomain.uy

As i said, im not able to access just using the plain and simple: somedomain.uy: Trying this results on: 404. That’s an error. (the google message).

I can't find a way to fix this and my question is: is there a way to setup a naked domain redirection to an alias domain? Or any other ideas about how can i make it work?

Thanks for reading, and excuse my simple english.

Comment: Did you set up the redirect in Google Apps, or elsewhere? Did you set up the A records as Google Apps instructs you to when you configure the redirect?

Comment: Hi Nick. Everything is set up in Google Apps. But maybe i didn't explain myself well. Our main domain is working fine, we can accesses to our app with or without www. The Alias domain is where we can't find a way to setup a naked redirect (which may be something that isn't allowed for alias and just for primary domains, and that's what my question is all about). Thanks for your time